# John the Ripper

Tags: pdf, john-the-ripper

I've already cracked a PDF with pdf2john but it doesn't show the password. What could be the problem? (The password isn't blank.)

Comment: OUTPUT: kali@Kali:/usr/share/john$ sudo john --show ~/Downloads/bash.txt   
/home/kali/Downloads/prj.pdf:

1 password hash cracked, 0 left

Comment: Yeah, that's not how you use that command. Try harder.